# Irrlicht Engine npot image rendering

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, irrlicht

I am using Irrlicht Engine(branch-ogles with svn newest version 4389) in iPhone and select the opengl-es2 driver.

However, it seems not to support non-power-of-two image texture rendering.
And I have successfully run an opengles2 example with non-power-of-two image rendering in iPhone.

So It may be that there is bug in COGLES2Driver or COGLES2Texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the wrap mode off of `GL_REPEAT`? NPO2 is not supported in OpenGLES2.0 for repeating textures.

Comment: Yes, it's the first thing coming to mind. @binzhang, please take a look at related question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7524506/405681

Comment: It works! Thank you. I should have found it before for the opengl es2 specification "OpenGL ES 2.0 supports non-power of two 2D textures, and cubemaps, with the caveat that mip- mapping and texture wrap modes other than clamp to edge are not supported".